# Overload function int... and long... simultaneously

Tags: java, overloading

I want to create two functions, say

```
long min(long...);
int min(int...);
```

But when I try to invoke the second i.e `min(1, 5)` one I get ambiguous method call

Is there workaround except renaming?

Comment: Is that a varg-args, or just a `so-on` message?

Comment: Is that a varg-args, or just a `so-on` message?

Comment: show how you are calling the second one

Comment: Which jdk are you using? I'm running fine with JDK7

Comment: Can't reproduce on jdk 7 either.

Comment: Excuse me I now can't reproduce:(, even on 1.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It is a known bug**

The behaviour you describe is a bug which has been fixed with Java 7. See details in the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html), section called "Changes in Most Specific Varargs Method Selection".

**The reason why it should compile**

Variable arity comes last in determining the most specific method. The rules to determine which vararg method applies when there are several are defined in [JLS 15.12.2.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.4) - here is an extract:

> One variable arity member method named m is more specific than another variable arity member method of the same name if either:
>   - [...]
>   - One member method has k parameters and the other has n parameters, where n ≥ k, and:
>
> - The types of the parameters of the first method are U1, ..., Uk-1, Uk[].
> - The types of the parameters of the other method are T1, ..., Tn-1, Tn[].
> - For all j from 1 to n, Uj <: Tj

In your case, k = n, and `U1[] = int[]` and `T1[] = long[]` so the determination can be made if `int <: long` or the opposite.

In other words, the type taken into account is not `int[]` vs. `long[]` but `int` vs `long`. And it happens that `int <: long` so the `int...` method should be chosen and it should compile.

**Conclusion:**

The code should (and does) compile fine with Java 7 but would not compile with Java 5 or 6. The code below prints `int` with Java 7:

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test1().m(1, 2);
    }
    int m(int... i) {
        System.out.println("int");
        return 0;
    }
    long m(long... i) {
        System.out.println("long");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Umm.. Did you try to compile it? It does not compile, at least for me.

Comment: @RohitJain I understand what is going on. Updating my answer.

Comment: @RohitJain It is a bug in Java <6

Comment: @assylias.. Well, in that case, it is not necessary that OP is using Java 7. Before Java 7 of course it does not work. So, I think my answer is valid, and does not needs a downvote. BTW, thanks for quoting that it works in Java 7. Haven't come through it till yet. :)

Comment: @RohitJain The release notes specifically state that it was a bug so although it did not compile with Java 5 or 6 your analysis of the reason is not correct if I may.

Comment: @RohitJain  In particular, based on your answer, if you remove the `int...` method, it should still not compile, but it does with Java 6, because the `int`s are converted to `long`s.

Comment: @assylias.. Well, I haven't used Java 7 till now. So, of course I could not have known that bug fix before you told me. And as I knew that was the problem, so I didn't bother to look for any bug fixes in Java 7.

Comment: @assylias.. Why would it not compile when `int...` is removed? That is the whole point. Both the method were valid, and hence there was ambiguity. If one method is removed, it will compile fine.

Comment: @assylias.. Anyways, +1 to your answer for bringing it to notice. And yes, I have added a link to your answer on my answer, to make it complete. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you invoke those method with an `integer`, **none** of the methods **provide exact match** for the argument, **as you used `var-args`**. Also, both the `var-args` can take `int` values separated by commas as argument. Hence the `ambiguous method` error.

When you call overloaded method, `Compiler` chooses the `exact match` first. Then the `nearest type` to cast.

Now, since `var-args` is just an `array`, compiler cannot decide which array to use while passing an `integer` value. As, neither arrays can be considered as `exact match` or `nearest conversion`. So, it takes both the method eligible for call.

There are lot more rules regarding the `method invocation` in case of `Overloading`. You can learn those from the `Java Language Specification`.

---

As in [@assylias answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13524464/1679863) this problem has been fixed in Java 7. But it will not work in Java version < 7.

Comment: +1 too. `long...` acts like `long[]` and `int[]` cannot be casted to `long[]` so it's not more specific

Comment: @assylias.. If used with var-args, it won't compile. I think that is the problem OP is facing. He might be using var-args on int and lon.

Comment: @RohitJain See my answer. The comparison is not between `int[]` and `long[]`, it is between `int` and `long`.

Comment: @assylias.. No. The decision here is, whether to convert `int` to `int[]` or `long[]`. Your code does not compile. Please test it.

Comment: @JanDvorak This is not the case: `int[]` is not more specific than `long[]` but `int...` is more specific than `long...`.

Answer (score 1):

Try  this

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().m(100L,512L);
        new Test().m(100,512);
    }

    int m(int... i) {
        System.out.println("int");
        return 0;
    }

    long m(long... i) {
        System.out.println("long");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @RiaD: it is working fine with jdk6. which jdk are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Those method signatures are unique, and are valid method overloads.

The problem must be in the method call argument. My guess is that you are calling the method with a literal, like:

```
min(100)
```

And it doesnt like that because 100 is an integer literal, but it gets automatically converted to a long.

disambiguating the method calls by using L at the end of long literals should fix the problem:

```
min(100L)
```

Also, you could make the calls explicit by using the Java Object Integer and Long, and let autoboxing take care of the conversion to primitive types:

```
min(new Long(100))
min(new Integer(100))
```

Comment: Are you considering the methods posted by OP as single argument method?

Comment: Passing literal `100` only fails in case of `var-args`. Else it works. Compiler chooses exact match.

Comment: -1 `new Integer(100)` doesn't help either. `100` is already an integer. http://ideone.com/bmU2ru