# Isn't ambiguity error?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] a){
          VarArgs obj = new VarArgs();
          obj.add(1,2);
}

class VarArgs{
       int add(int size, Integer... params){
       }
}
```

This code works. But I thought it will give ambiguity error. Because of type casting.

How does it work?

Comment: `2` gets autoboxed to an `Integer` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `reference to call ambiguous` error happens when there are *two* methods that are equally applicable; and in fact, one common way to fix that error is to remove one of the two methods. (See [Compiler error : reference to call ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14053596/978917).)

In your case, there's only one method to begin with, so there's no ambiguity: the `2` simply gets autoboxed into `Integer.valueOf(2)`, then into `new Integer[] { Integer.valueOf(2) }`.

Comment: Thanks. Other scenario --> If signature is `add(Integer... params, int size)` , then I will get ambiguity. Am I right?

Comment: @GopsAB That won't compile, because an ellipses parameter must the the last parameter.

Comment: @JornVernee Thanks