# Method Overloading in Java showing ambiguity for non primitive types and non parent-child relations classes

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

I'm confused in below examples. some one can please explain me why in Example 1 it will print "st" and in Example 2 give compile time ambiguity for non primitive types and non parent-child relations classes.

Example 1

```
public class FinalTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        name(null);
    }

    public static void name(String s) {
        System.out.println("st");
    }

    public static void name(Object s) {
        System.out.println("obj");
    }
}
```

Example 2

```
public class FinalTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        name(null);
    }

    public static void name(String s) {
        System.out.println("st");
    }

    public static void name(Integer s) {
        System.out.println("obj");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiler error : reference to call ambiguous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053596/compiler-error-reference-to-call-ambiguous)

Comment: No its not duplicate, it may fall in same category but its a different scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Example 1 `public static void name(String s)` is more specific than `public static void name(Object s)`. So the `null` in `name(null);` is supposed to be a `String` object being `null`.

But in Example 2 both  `public static void name(String s)` and  `public static void name(Integer s)` are equal in specific. So both method `name(String)` in `FinalTest` and method `name(Integer)` in `FinalTest` match for `name(null);`.

See [15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)  for a detailed description.

The following should work:

```
public class FinalTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = null;
        name(s);
        Object o = null;
        name(o);
        Integer i = null;
        name(i);
    }

    public static void name(String s) {
        System.out.println("String");
    }

    public static void name(Object s) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    public static void name(Integer s) {
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }
}
```

Comment: Axel, I didn't get what you mean by "more specific" and "are equal in specific"..?