# Java method call is ambiguous

Tags: java, compiler-errors

there are 2 methods:

```
public static TermsQueryBuilder termsQuery(String name, int... values) {
    return new TermsQueryBuilder(name, values);
}
public static TermsQueryBuilder termsQuery(String name, Object... values) {
    return new TermsQueryBuilder(name, values);
}
```

when i called

```
termsQuery("operatorType", 1);
```

it says that is ambiguous.

Please Help ...

all the methods are in Elasticsearch,for example:

```
public static TermsQueryBuilder termsQuery(String name, String... values) {
    return new TermsQueryBuilder(name, values);
}
public static TermsQueryBuilder termsQuery(String name, int... values) {
    return new TermsQueryBuilder(name, values);
}
public static TermsQueryBuilder termsQuery(String name, long... values) {
    return new TermsQueryBuilder(name, values);
}
...
public static TermsQueryBuilder termsQuery(String name, Object... values) {
    return new TermsQueryBuilder(name, values);
}
```

when I called `termsQuery("operationType","1")`,  not ambiguous.

when I called `termsQuery("operationType",1)`,  ambiguous.

when I called `termsQuery("operationType",Arrays.asList(searchParam.getOperatorType())`, not ambiguous.

puzzled.....

Comment: this java notation is to make the method accept a variable amount of (in this case) int parameter.

To handle this variable amount of variables you can access it like an array.

Comment: You should never use `Object` as varargs; this is the worst example.

Comment: Surely the constructors being called are also ambiguous?

Comment: That's a great point, @EJP. I wonder how one would force [TermsQueryBuilder(String, int...)](http://xbib.org/elasticsearch/2.1.1/apidocs/org/elasticsearch/index/query/TermsQueryBuilder.html#TermsQueryBuilder-java.lang.String-int...-) to be called, when [TermsQueryBuilder(String, Object...)](http://xbib.org/elasticsearch/2.1.1/apidocs/org/elasticsearch/index/query/TermsQueryBuilder.html#TermsQueryBuilder-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) also exists.

Comment: I clarified my answer to try to say in very few words why the String version is not ambiguous but the int version is. To reduce your puzzlement, perhaps check out [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053596/compiler-error-reference-to-call-ambiguous) which references the parts of the JLS dealing with method overloading. Hope that helps.

Comment: All constructors using `<any primitive>...` are not callable directly because for all of those  `Object...` is ambiguous. Compiler error message clearly states that.

Comment: @EJP The constructors are being called with arrays from the builders so they are not ambiguous.

Comment: I was able to make it work by casting the value to object before sending it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply rename one or both of your methods and the error will go away.

You cannot overload this method with the signatures your desire, because your call can be matched by both method definitions, and the types `int` and `Object` are not in a superclass-subclass relationship, so neither is more specific than the other.

Consider

```
integerTermsQuery
```

and

```
objectTermsQuery
```

**EDIT**

As you point out in your comments, the version with the `String...` parameter does not conflict with `Object...` and arrays are covariant with `String` being a subclass of `Object`.

Comment: there are more methods like:

public static TermsQueryBuilder termsQuery(String name, String... values) {
        return new TermsQueryBuilder(name, values);
}

when I called termsQuery("operationType", "1");
it is not ambiguous.
these methods are from elasticsearch Java package.

Comment: Well that's correct because `String` is a subclass of `Object` and so the method with `String...` is more specific so it can be called without ambiguity. The problem here is with `int`. `int` is not a subclass of `Object`, but `Integer` is, even though `int` autoboxes to `Integer`. This is pretty tricky. Have you tried arrays?

Comment: I tried termsQuery("operationType",Arrays.asList(searchParam.getOperatorType()) ,  not ambiguous.   Thank u for your answer!

Comment: Hey, that's a nice approach.

Answer (score 3):

All constructors using varargs `<any primitive>...` are not callable directly using comma separated list of primitives if  `Object...` exists because for all of those `Object...` is ambiguous. Compiler error message clearly states that.

We could call them using arrays:

`termsQuery("operatorType", new int[]{1, 2, 3})`.

`TermsQueryBuilder termsQuery(String name, Object... values)` and `TermsQueryBuilder termsQuery(String name, String... values)` are not ambiguous because while `String` is also an `Object` it is a more special object than just `Object`.

The following code works and should show what happens exactly:

```
public class TestAmbiguous {

 public static TermsQueryBuilder termsQuery(String name, int... values) {
    return new TermsQueryBuilder(name, values);
 }
 public static TermsQueryBuilder termsQuery(String name, double... values) {
    return new TermsQueryBuilder(name, values);
 }
 public static TermsQueryBuilder termsQuery(String name, Object... values) {
    return new TermsQueryBuilder(name, values);
 }
 public static TermsQueryBuilder termsQuery(String name, String... values) {
    return new TermsQueryBuilder(name, values);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  TermsQueryBuilder builder;
  builder = termsQuery("operatorType", 1, 1.0, 1.0f, "test", new Integer(1), new Double(1), new Float(1), new String("test"));
  builder = termsQuery("operatorType", "test", new String("test"));
  builder = termsQuery("operatorType", new int[]{1, 2, 3});
  builder = termsQuery("operatorType", new double[]{1, 2, 3});
  builder = termsQuery("operatorType", new float[]{1, 2, 3});
  builder = termsQuery("operatorType", (Object[]) new Float[]{1f, 2f, 3f});
 }
}

class TermsQueryBuilder {
 TermsQueryBuilder(String name, int... values) {
  System.out.println("_____________________________________");
  System.out.println("primitive int");
  for (int i = 0 ; i < values.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(values[i]);
  }
 }
 TermsQueryBuilder(String name, double... values) {
  System.out.println("_____________________________________");
  System.out.println("primitive double");
  for (int i = 0 ; i < values.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(values[i]);
  }
 }
 TermsQueryBuilder(String name, Object... values) {
  System.out.println("_____________________________________");
  System.out.println("Any objects");
  for (int i = 0 ; i < values.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(values[i].getClass());
   System.out.println(values[i]);
  }
 }
 TermsQueryBuilder(String name, String... values) {
  System.out.println("_____________________________________");
  System.out.println("String objects");
  for (int i = 0 ; i < values.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(values[i].getClass());
   System.out.println(values[i]);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's ambiguous because `1` can be automatically converted to `Integer`, which is accepted by the `Object` signature. It can also be directly accepted by the `int` signature.

You should make these two methods unambiguous, by either renaming the methods, or not having such a generic argument list (`Object...`)

Comment: Careful. The fact that 1 is both an int and an Object is not the whole story here. Note how the OP stated in the question that passing `"1"`, even though it is both a string and an object is **NOT** ambiguous. The problem being experienced by the OP is due to `int...` and `Object...` not being in a relationship that allows Java to choose the most specific method, based on the language definition.