# reference to submit is ambiguous: <T>submit(Callable<T>) in ExecutorService and method submit(Runnable) in ExecutorService match

Tags: java, multithreading, jenkins, executorservice, callable

I am registering a callable and saving it into a future object like this:

```
final Future<SomeObject> objectFuture= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5).submit(
                    () -> methodReturnsSomeObject(someValue));
```

I am getting the following compilation error but its building locally:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /c:/1/5889/001/target/clover/src/com/... reference to submit is ambiguous
```

both method submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable) in java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService and method submit(java.lang.Runnable) in java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService match

This happens when there are ambiguity in overloaded methods e.g. Integer... and int... according to [Compiler error : reference to call ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053596/compiler-error-reference-to-call-ambiguous). I do not see why its showing this here. I am clearly passing a Callable here in the above method. Please let me know how it is ambiguous? Also, since my maven build is passing locally and not in Jenkins, do I need to look at the Jenkins server configuration? Thanks in advance

Java version: 1.8
Maven Version: 3.0.5

Comment: Why are you "clearly passing a Callable"? Your lambda matches `Runnable` just as well.

Comment: Try removing the invalid (and extraneous) cast `(ThreadPoolExecutor)`.

Comment: Hi @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic, yes I agree, that's not obvious. Though, I am wondering how its building locally.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`submit()` has 2 overloads with one argument. The arguments are both functional interfaces, with the following methods:

- [`submit(Callable<T> task)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-): [`T call()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html#call--)
- [`submit(Runnable task)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-): [`void run()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html#run--)

Your lambda expression is `() -> methodReturnsSomeObject(someValue)`.

If the method hadn't returned anything, i.e. was a `void` method, it could only implement `Runnable`, so there would have been no ambiguity.

But since the method has a return value matching type `T` (`SomeObject` in your case), the lambda expression can implement `Callable`, but it can also implement `Runnable` by ignoring/discarding the return value. Having it implement `Callable` is of course preferable.

Be aware that some compilers will resolve to `Callable`, especially newer versions of the compiler, which will have improved inference handling, so you will not always experience this issue.

To resolve an ambiguity, cast to the parameter type you desire. In this case, we desire `Callable`, so:

```java
final Future<SomeObject> objectFuture = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5).submit(
                    (Callable<SomeObject>) () -> methodReturnsSomeObject(someValue));
```

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, that explains it. One follow up, in my local I have Java 8 and maven and same Java and maven configuration in Jenkins. What could be the reason apart from java and maven its building locally?

Comment: @SiddharthShankar Different versions of Java, of the Java compiler?

Comment: You can enforce `Callable` or `Runnable` by using dedicated brackets: `() -> (methodReturnsSomeObject(someValue))` will never be a `Runnable`, as an expression in brackets is not a statement. And `() -> { methodReturnsSomeObject(someValue); }` will never be a `Callable`, as it has no `return`.